# SimpleSchema validation for object array

Tags: javascript, meteor, simple-schema

I would like to validate this object array:

```
[
    {
        _id     : 'NpxZFT4TwfDvwbtKX',
        parent: 'T4TwfDvwbtKXNpxZF',
        order:  1
    }
]
```

How do I do that, as this is not working:

```
new SimpleSchema({
    _id   : { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id },
    parent: { type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id },
    order : { type: Number }
})
```

How would the validation look like by using `check()`?

Comment: Why is the SimpleSchema validation not working? What is the exact error given? Do you try to validate the array as awhole or each item in the array with the schema?

Comment: I'm trying to validate the complete array not each item

Comment: Which is why the schema refuses your input. The schema is only fitting the scheme of the several item content but because you pass an array it refuses the input. Where exactly do you use it? In a validated method? There may be an easy solution to that. Can you please post a small code where you actually got your array refused?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'm using it in a validated method.

Comment: Yeah, easy thing. Just post a snippet of the method, I make it work and post it as answer ;-)

Comment: No need to post, I already make an example for you, give me 5 min.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The cool thing about validated method is, that you can use a seperate schema for your method than for the documents. This allows you to pass objects and arrays and anything else to the method and process your documents in behalf of the data.

So what about the schema you created before? This is still in use! It is checking FOR EACH insert or update of a document in your collection, if the document fits the given schema.

**Code Example:**

```
import {Meteor} from 'meteor/meteor';
import {Mongo} from 'meteor/mongo';
import {ValidatedMethod} from 'meteor/mdg:validated-method';
import {Random} from 'meteor/random';

import SimpleSchema from 'simpl-schema';

// schema for document on collectionm level
const documentSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    // id optional otherwise you can't insert new docs
    _id: {type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id, optional: true},
    parent: {type: SimpleSchema.RegEx.Id},
    order: {type: Number}
});

// attach schema to a new collection
const testCollection = new Mongo.Collection("testcollection");
testCollection.schema = documentSchema;
testCollection.attachSchema(documentSchema)


// create method schema
// see that we attach the document schema
// as type of the items of the array
const methodSchema = new SimpleSchema({
    data: {type: Array},
    "data.$": {type: documentSchema},
});

// insert method using the method schema
const insertArrayMethod = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: "insert.array.method",
    validate: methodSchema.validator(),
    run({data}){
        const ret = [];
        for (let input of data) {
            const tmp = Object.assign({}, input);
            tmp._id = testCollection.insert(input);
            ret.push(tmp);
        }
        return ret;
    },
});

// update method using the method schema
const updateArrayMethod = new ValidatedMethod({
    name: "update.array.method",
    validate: methodSchema.validator(),
    run({data}){
        const ret = [];
        for (let input of data) {
            ret.push(testCollection.update(input._id, {$set: {parent: input.parent, order: input.order}}));
        }
        return ret;
    },
});


Meteor.startup(() => {
    const data = [
        {parent: Random.id(17), order: 0},
        {parent: Random.id(17), order: 1},
        {parent: Random.id(17), order: 2},
    ];
    console.log("insert data")
    console.log(data);

    const results = Meteor.call("insert.array.method", {data: data});
    console.log("insert result");
    console.log(results);

    for (let element of results) {
        element.order += 5;
    }
    console.log("update data");
    console.log(results);

    // note thet the input variablle in the validated method has to be called data
    const updateResult = Meteor.call("update.array.method", {data: results});
    console.log("update result");
    console.log(updateResult);
});
```

**Console Output:**

```
I20170701-12:21:38.302(2)? insert data        
I20170701-12:21:38.319(2)? [ { parent: 'wkh3C6NSvZqrewxLh', order: 0 },
I20170701-12:21:38.322(2)?   { parent: 'ezfBAtZrgXgG8dANy', order: 1 },
I20170701-12:21:38.342(2)?   { parent: 'H4eXyR6FJ9sts6Nn2', order: 2 } ]
I20170701-12:21:38.616(2)? insert result
I20170701-12:21:38.621(2)? [ { parent: 'wkh3C6NSvZqrewxLh',
I20170701-12:21:38.624(2)?     order: 0,
I20170701-12:21:38.626(2)?     _id: 'et4hCu2osH7DnbhHo' },
I20170701-12:21:38.633(2)?   { parent: 'ezfBAtZrgXgG8dANy',
I20170701-12:21:38.636(2)?     order: 1,
I20170701-12:21:38.641(2)?     _id: 'ysH3NaydR6PwdTQCr' },
I20170701-12:21:38.656(2)?   { parent: 'H4eXyR6FJ9sts6Nn2',
I20170701-12:21:38.659(2)?     order: 2,
I20170701-12:21:38.660(2)?     _id: 'AQExATqWhGr26FN7A' } ]
I20170701-12:21:38.673(2)? update data
I20170701-12:21:38.681(2)? [ { parent: 'wkh3C6NSvZqrewxLh',
I20170701-12:21:38.683(2)?     order: 5,
I20170701-12:21:38.684(2)?     _id: 'et4hCu2osH7DnbhHo' },
I20170701-12:21:38.696(2)?   { parent: 'ezfBAtZrgXgG8dANy',
I20170701-12:21:38.698(2)?     order: 6,
I20170701-12:21:38.700(2)?     _id: 'ysH3NaydR6PwdTQCr' },
I20170701-12:21:38.701(2)?   { parent: 'H4eXyR6FJ9sts6Nn2',
I20170701-12:21:38.705(2)?     order: 7,
I20170701-12:21:38.707(2)?     _id: 'AQExATqWhGr26FN7A' } ]
I20170701-12:21:38.712(2)? update result
I20170701-12:21:38.714(2)? [ 1, 1, 1 ]
```

**Summary:**

method-schema - validates the input for a validated method
document-schema - validates the input/update object for a mongo collection